# I keep getting error from crawl data from certain forum

Tags: python, json, dataframe, web-crawler

I want to get information from a forum, Dcard.
I have also built a function to arrange the data I receive.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests
from requests_html import HTML
import re
import openpyxl

def Crawl(ID):
        link='https://www.dcard.tw/_api/posts/'+str(ID)
        requ=requests.get(link)
        rejs=requ.json()
        return(pd.DataFrame(
                data=
                [{'ID':rejs['id'],
                  'title':rejs['title'],
                  'content':rejs['content'],
                  'excerpt':rejs['excerpt'],
                  'createdAt':rejs['createdAt'],
                  'updatedAt':rejs['updatedAt'],
                  'commentCount':rejs['commentCount'],
                  'forumName':rejs['forumName'],
                  'forumAlias':rejs['forumAlias'],
                  'gender':rejs['gender'],
                  'likeCount':rejs['likeCount'],
                  'reactions':rejs['reactions'],
                  'topics':rejs['topics']}],
                columns=['ID',"title","content","excerpt","createdAt","updateAt","commentCount",
                         "forumName","forumAlias","gender","likeCount","reactionns","topics"])
        )
test3=open('D:/Quinna/爬蟲/test4.txt','w',encoding='UTF-8')
p=requests.Session()
url=requests.get("https://www.dcard.tw/search?query=%E5%88%86%E6%89%8B&forum=relationship")
soup=BeautifulSoup(url.text,"html.parser")
a_tags=soup.find_all('h2')
for tag in a_tags:
        a=tag.select_one('a').get('href')[18:27] #get the ID from the API
        print(Crawl(a))
```

However, whenever I tried, the error message still comes up.
Is the json not a valid format? How to amend it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Quinna\爬蟲\test4.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(Crawl(a))
  File "D:\Quinna\爬蟲\test4.py", line 12, in Crawl
    rejs=requ.json()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This this. You aren't getting the IDs in a proper way.

```
    Replace this line: 
    a = tag.select_one('a').get('href')[18:27]

    to this line: 
    a = tag.select_one('a').get('href').split('/')[-1]
```

Comment: I changed the code, but the error still came out.
But the result of print are longer than the origin.